# Why does the Home Page break with failed micropost submission - Michael Hartl Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am following the Michael Hartl tutorial and after [Listing 10.14](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#fig-home_with_proto_feed), he states that

> There is one subtlety, though: on failed micropost submission, the
>   Home page expects an @feed_items instance variable, so failed
>   submissions currently break

which is true. But I do not understand how a failed micropost is related to @feed_items. The feed is being pulled out from the database right? from `Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)` in the user model. So even if the a micropost is empty and fails to be saved, the feed should pull the other posts already saved. Why would we need to add `@feed_items = []` in [Listing 10.42](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-microposts_create_action_with_feed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page being rendered for `StaticPagesController.home` expects a non-nil `@feed_items`.

The submission code *renders the template directly*, it does *not* redirect to the static controller which retrieves them itself: it must create something for the template to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I forgot that rendering does not mean going to the controller.